# Changing class component to functional component : use method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert class component to functional component,
but having a trouble calling method 'resize' of child component 'Dog.js'

1. App.js

```js
function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const dogs = [
      new Dog("#fff", 1, 2)
    ]

    dogs[0].resize(stageWidth, stageHeight) // here is what I want to perform - now it is undefined

   },[])
 ...
 }
```

2. Dog.js

```js
function Dog(color, speed, total) {

  Dog.resize = (stageWidth, stageHeight) => {
      const gap = Math.ceil(stageWidth / (this.total - 2));
      ...
  };

}
export default Dog;
```

please let me know how to use the 'resize' method of Dog.js in App.js,
or what i need to change in my code structure.
(or just keeping the structure of class component is better?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: Is `Dog` supposed to be a React component? If so, it isn't valid React component. React components accept a single props object. React components also do not reach into other react components to invoke functions. Can you provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

To call resize Dog.js method from App.js you need to change Dog function like this:

```
function Dog(color, speed, total) {

  this.resize = (stageWidth, stageHeight) => {
      const gap = Math.ceil(stageWidth / (this.total - 2));
      ...
  };

}
export default Dog;
```